# Use of switch case in Power Automate is feasible or not for this scenario

Tags: powerapps, power-automate

I am creating a Flow in Power Apps switch is not going to next case, I have created stages in the form, each stage will invoke when we hit the next stage button on the form as you can show in the image. Against every stage I am sending an email but it is not going to next case. Is it true to use switch like that ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch case will work only once on that Flow execution, then it will go to the next step of Flow and not the next case in switch condition.

So you have to trigger that Flow again on some status change when you want to go to next switch case branch.

Lets say, if you want to send email to "Recruiting team" and then "Admin team" - these steps has to be in sequence in same Flow. If you want to send email either to "Recruiting team" or "Admin team" based on Employee department or status, then it can be in Switch case.

If you want to send email to "Recruiting team" on status "Hired" and then emailing "Admin team" on status "Joined" - then you have to trigger the same Flow on status change and Switch case will work.